# "Converted/Optimized" C# Code - HTTP Client Response Code 404 Error

Tags: c#

I'm trying after "converted/optimized" a C# Unity Project to my Visual Studio in C# to work for me (the code)...

i used this github lib for nft.storage
https://github.com/filipepolizel/unity-nft-storage/blob/main/NFTStorageClient.cs

If i call then with:

`string pathtofile = @"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "testfile.txt";`

`await NFTStorageTest.Upload(NFTStorageTest.nftStorageApiUrl, pathtofile);`

i get this error:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at Main.net.NFTStorageTest.Upload(String uri, String pathFile) in C:\...\NFTStorageTest.cs:line 173`

Here is my Code:

```
    // nft.storage API endpoint 
    internal static readonly string nftStorageApiUrl = "https://api.nft.storage/";

    // HTTP client to communicate with nft.storage
    internal static readonly HttpClient nftClient = new HttpClient();

    // http client to communicate with IPFS API
    internal static readonly HttpClient ipfsClient = new HttpClient();

    // nft.storage API key
    public string apiToken = "XXX";

    public void Start()
    {
        nftClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        if (apiToken != null)
        {
            nftClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken);
        }
        else
        {
            // log in console in case no API key is found during initialization
            Console.WriteLine("Starting NFT Storage Client without API key, please call 'SetApiToken' method before using class methods.");
        }
    }

    public async Task<NFTStorageUploadResponse> UploadDataFromFile(string path)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Uploading...");
        return await UploadDataFromString(data);
    }


    public async Task<NFTStorageUploadResponse> UploadDataFromString(string data)
    {
        string requestUri = nftStorageApiUrl + "/upload";
        string rawResponse = await Upload(requestUri, data);
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawResponse);

        NFTStorageUploadResponse parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NFTStorageUploadResponse>(jsonString);
        return parsedResponse;
    }

    public static async Task<string> Upload(string uri, string pathFile)
    {

        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathFile);

        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("*/*");

            //Send it
            var response = await nftClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }`
```

whats my mistake and how can i fix it?

Comment: You’re adding an extra slash. Your nftStorageApiUrl already has a slash at the end. You don’t need to append “/upload”, just need “upload”

Comment: @Lee I removed the Slash, but i get the same Error Message :/

Comment: The error message indicates the url is incorrect, if removing the slash doesn’t fix it. Double check the url

Comment: You are calling the upload method directly which was originally private, not using the proper uploaddata in the source code which constructs the right uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await NFTStorageTest.Upload(NFTStorageTest.nftStorageApiUrl, pathtofile);
```

This should be called with

```
$”{NFTStorageTest.nftStorageApiUrl}upload”
```

See the original file
https://github.com/filipepolizel/unity-nft-storage/blob/45bedb5c421982645bc9bf49d12beed8f2cdb9d3/NFTStorageClient.cs#L297

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Lee :) I hope i understand it correct: await NFTStorageTest.UploadDataFromString(pathtofilejson); < with this i get no 404, but now i get {"Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."} in this code line var response = await nftClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
.... im out of my ideas

Comment: i got it :) i just added before postasync await Start(); and boom, it works :) thank you too for helping :)

Comment: Based on the source code think you need to call the start method to add the auth headers

Comment: Yea that i figured out yesterday that i must first call the auth headers method with start()